# Sequelize `order` and `limit` missing in the resulting query

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using `sequelize` package, seeing unexpected queries being generated. Table's just `id`, `date`, `pker` (for relevant columns).

Sequelize:

```
    const pkers= await db.Pkrecords.count({
      distinct: "pker",
      group: ["pker"],
      limit: 3,
      order: [["pker", "DESC"]],
      where: {
        date: {
          [Op.gt]: dateWeekStart,
          [Op.lt]: dateWeekEnd,
        },
      },
    });
```

Resulting query:

```
Executing (default): 
SELECT 
 `pker`, 
 count(DISTINCT(`id`)) AS `count` 
FROM `pkrecords` AS `pkrecords` 
WHERE (`pkrecords`.`date` > '2023-01-15 05:00:00' AND `pkrecords`.`date` < '2023-01-22 04:59:59') 
GROUP BY `pker`;
```

`limit` and `order` are completely ignored, I tried changing the values and replacing `order` value with `count`. Is there something I'm missing? Results are not ordered and everything that matches the date range is showing.

Comment: `count` function is to just return the record count with conditions. `order` or `limit` is not a valid option for this function. ref: https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-count

If you need to show records with count as an attribute, you can use `findAll`

Comment: Moreover if you wish to paginate records and get the total count at the same time you can use `findAndCountAll`